# Array/Dictionary in array isEmpty shotrcut

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, is-empty

Let say i have some teams with different players in each one of them:

```
var PlayersShowByTeams:[String:[String]]=[:]
```

Now.. I want to do something in my code if this array is empty

My question is.. Can i check if the array is empty with a shortcut ?? instead of.. 
make another array of the name of all the teams like that:

```
var teams:[String] = []
```

And then to check if every team is empty from players by the sign and (&&) like that:

```
if(playersShowByTeam[teams[0].count=0 && playersShowByTeam[teams[1].count=0 && playersShowByTeam[teams[2].count=0 //.. and so on
{
//do something
}
```

If i tried to use .isEmpty like that:

```
if (playerShowByTeam.isEmpty){//do something}
```

Even though there is no more players in those teams in the array it's show me false (when i print that).. because the names of the teams are still inside.

1. There is a different between using .isEmpty or using .count=0 ?
2. How can i make the if in the code shorter ?

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

```
func allTeamsEmpty(teams: [String : [String]]) -> Bool {
    return teams.filter{teamName, teamMembers in !teamMembers.isEmpty}.isEmpty
}
```

This function filters the dictionary so that non-empty teams remain. If the dictionary is empty after this filtration, then all teams must have been filtered out for being non empty.

Comment: problem.. I tried to copy that func and it's shows me an error: "value of tuple type has no member isEmpty"

Comment: If this answer satisfied your question, please upvote and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Check if at least **1 team exists**:

```
var hasTeams: Bool {
    return PlayersShowByTeams.keys.count > 0
}
```

Check if at least **1 team has players**:

```
var hasTeamWithPlayers: Bool {
    return PlayersShowByTeams.contains{ !$1.isEmpty }
}
```